# KeyError 43L in python

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I want to assign a list for dictionary inside another dictionary but i get a key error
you can find the file here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9n35b41rzuxjkk8/plan1.txt?dl=0

```
Code, Title, Lec, Lab, Cr, Prereq, Year, Semester

ARAB110 ,  Arabic Language Skills I ,  3 ,  0 , 3,  - ,  1 ,  1 
CHEMY101 ,  General Chemistry I ,  3 ,  3 , 4,  - ,  2 ,  2 
ENGL154 ,  Language Development I ,  3 ,  0 , 3,  - ,  1 ,  1 
ENGL155 ,  Language Development II ,  3 ,  0 , 3,  ENGL154 ,  1 ,  2 
ENGL219 ,  Technical Report Writing ,  3 ,  0 , 3,  ENGL155 ,  2 ,  1
```

i want to create a dict for every year and inside every year a dictonary of every semester contains a list of all codes in this semester

```
curri = read_csv('senior_data/plan1.txt')
curri = curri.sort([' Year',' Semester '],ascending=[1,1]) 

cur = {}
cur['1']={}
cur['2']={}
cur['3']={}
cur['4']={}

cur['1']['1'] = {}
cur['1']['2'] = {}
cur['2']['1'] = {}
cur['2']['2'] = {}
cur['3']['1'] = {}
cur['3']['2'] = {}
cur['3']['3'] = {}
cur['4']['1'] = {}
cur['4']['2'] = {}


i=0
c_list = []
for xxx in cur:
    for y in cur[xxx]:
        print (xxx+" "+y)
        for row in curri.iterrows():
            if(str(curri[' Year'][i]) == xxx and str(curri[' Semester '][i] == y)):   
                print (xxx+":"+y+ curri['Code'][i])
                c_list.append(curri['Code'][i])
            i=i+1
            cur[xxx][y] = c_list
            c_list = []
```

when I remove the third loop it's work fine!

this is the output:

```
1 1
1:1 ARAB110 
1:1 ENGL154 
1:1 ENGL155 
1:1 ISLM101 
1:1 ITCS101 
1:1 ITCS102 
1:1 MATHS101 
1:1 MATHS102 
1:1 PHYCS101 
1:1 PHYCS102 
1 2
```

the error is

```
KeyError: 42L

---> 24             if(str(curri[' Year'][i]) == xxx and str(curri[' Semester ']
```

Comment: `element in seqence` gives you the element, not the index, are you aware of that? Use a debugger or output the values to find out at what place exactly things are not as expected. Also, please quote the full error message and don't put tags into the title, they should remain separate.

Comment: Please paste the error traceback that you are getting because your code is partial and we cannot run it.

Comment: i can get the elements of the first xxx and first y only

Comment: 1 1
    1:1 ARAB110 
    1:1 ENGL154 
    1:1 ENGL155 
    1:1 ISLM101 
    1:1 ITCS101 
    1:1 ITCS102 
    1:1 MATHS101 
    1:1 MATHS102 
    1:1 PHYCS101 
    1:1 PHYCS102 
    1 2

Comment: @Ms.J The full error message you are getting for the `KeyError` error, please copy it and include it in your question so that we know what is wrong.

Comment: Your code snippet gives this error message: `NameError: name 'curri' is not defined`. Please paste the full code that causes your error.

Comment: curri = read_csv('senior_data/plan1.txt')
curri = curri.sort([' Year',' Semester '],ascending=[1,1])

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9n35b41rzuxjkk8/plan1.txt?dl=0

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Add these lines to your code in the question and show the first lines of the csv file `plan1.txt`.  Where does `read_csv()` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your increment of `i`should happen in the most inner loop.

Assuming that the rows are dictionaries, this could work:

```
c_list = []
for xxx in cur:
    for y in cur[xxx]:
        print (xxx+" "+y)
        for row in curri.iterrows():
            if(str(row[' Year']) == xxx and str(row[' Semester '] == y)):   
                print (xxx+":"+y+ row['Code'])
                c_list.append(row['Code'])
            cur[xxx][y] = c_list
            c_list = []
```

If not try this:

```
c_list = []
for xxx in cur:
    for y in cur[xxx]:
        print (xxx+" "+y)
        i = 0
        for row in curri.iterrows():
            if(str(curri[' Year'][i]) == xxx and str(curri[' Semester '][i] == y)):   
                print (xxx+":"+y+ curri['Code'][i])
                c_list.append(curri['Code'][i])
            i=i+1
            cur[xxx][y] = c_list
            c_list = []
```

In Python it is typically not necessary to increment an index by hand:

```
c_list = []
for xxx in cur:
    for y in cur[xxx]:
        print (xxx+" "+y)
        for i, row in enumerate(curri):
            if(str(curri[' Year'][i]) == xxx and str(curri[' Semester '][i] == y)):   
                print (xxx+":"+y+ curri['Code'][i])
                c_list.append(curri['Code'][i])
            cur[xxx][y] = c_list
            c_list = []
```